# CMake: library not created

Tags: cmake, dependencies, subdirectory

I have a project directory A which has sub directories B and C.
I want C as a shared object library and let B use it.
The CMakeLists.txt looks like following -

A

```
...
add_subdirectory(C)
add_subdirectory(B)
...
```

[ 1) Does this ensure that C is cmake(ed) first and then B? ]

B

```
...
pkg_check_modules(C_LIB REQUIRED C)
target_link_libraries(B C_LIB)
...
```

C

```
...
add_library (C SHARED ./*c)
...
```

I get an error in build which says no package c found.

However, if I have directory C in the same hierarchy as A, I am able to get the linking of B and C properly.

I want to place my code in A and get the dependencies correct. What am I missing in my CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this ensure that C is cmake(ed) first and then B?

No. It doesn't ensure that there even is a `C` nor `B` project, and it doesn't ensure that they will build at all. It just sources/includes (in a special way) `C/CMakeLists.txt` and `B/CMakeLists.txt` files, that's all.

> add_library (C SHARED ./*c)

This is invalid, unless you have a source file named `*c`. You want:

```
file(GLOB sources ./*c)
add_library(C SHARED ${sources})
```

The add_library doesn't understand globulations.

> pkg_check_modules(C_LIB REQUIRED C)
>   target_link_libraries(B C_LIB)

This is strange. You don't have a `pkg-config` modules named "C" do you? You probably want:

```
 target_link_libraries(B C)
```

or better try to always explicit tell `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` or `INTERFACE`:

```
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC C)
```

This will ensure that B has the interface include paths that were (or will be?) added to `C`, and that when an executable is build that uses `B`, that `C` is linked with/against it. It does not mean "build `C` before `B`" it means: use interface of `C` to build `B`.

Maybe try it like this:

A

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(A)
add_subdirectory(C)
add_subdirectory(B)
```

B

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(B)
add_executable(B ./source1.c)
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC C)
```

C

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(C)
add_library(C SHARED sourcec.c)
target_include_directories(C PUBLIC ./) # so when compiling B it uses this include dir
```